# CSS div style, javascript canvas color change

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I am having an issue trying to get these 3 divs to line up on the same horizontal pane.

I will also like to know if it is possible to have the color of my circle change based on a value of a variable. I would greatly appreciate an example function.

```
  <html>
      <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        .circle
        {
        width:115px;
        height:115px;
        border-radius:250px;
        font-size:20px;
        color:#fff;
        line-height:115px;
        text-align:center;
        background:#000
        }
    </style>

     <div id="container"  style=" border: 2px coral solid; width:100%; height:120px;"> 

       <div class="circle">Hello</div>

       <div id="leadInfo" style="width:37%; height:115px; float:left; background-color:yellow;"> </div>

       <div id="leadInfo2" style="width:37.5%; height:115px; float:right;  background-color:blue;"> </div>

     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well for one, you spelled "left" wrong

Answer (score 0):

First you wrote

```
float: leftt;
```

Instead of

```
float: left;
```

Also, try adjusting one of the yellow circles to be less then 37.5%, it somehow goes over 100% in total and jumps down. So 37% will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container"  style=" border: 3px coral solid; width:100%; height:auto;"> 
    <div id="colorwheel" style="width:25%; float:left; border: 3px coral solid;">
    <canvas id="circlecanvas" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById("circlecanvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        context.fillStyle="red";
        context.fill()
    </script>
    </div>
    <div id="leadInfo" style="width:37.2%; height:108px; float:right; background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red;"> </div>
    <div id="leadInfo" style="width:37.2%; height:108px; float:right; background-color:yellow;border:1px solid red;"> </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

And about changing the color of a circle on canvas...

No, you can't change anything you've drawn on the canvas (including your circle).

That's because canvas doesn't "remember" where it drew your circle.  Your circle becomes an un-remembered group of pixels on the canvas.

Therefore, if you want to change anything on the canvas, you must erase the canvas and redraw your circle using the fillStyle in your variable.

```
// create a variable to hold your desired fill color
var myFillColor="gold";

// clear the canvas
context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); 

// set the context.fillStyle to your variable
context.fillStyle=myFillColor;

// redraw your circle
context.beginPath();
context.arc(50, 50, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
context.fill();
```

Important note: context.arc is a path command and every group of path commands must be preceeded by context.beginPath.  beginPath tells the browser you are finished drawing the previous path and are now drawing a new path. Failing to start new paths with beginPath will cause your next context.fill (or context.stroke) command to redraw all previous path commands.